# Is there a way to write Heap Sort Algorithm in SML using the Foldr or Foldl functions?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I would like to know if there is a way to write a heap-sort algorithm using SML's Foldr or Foldl function. I cannot find an example online and I wanted to know if anyone could give me some sort of guidance on this matter. I want to implement the sorting algorithm using a higher order function with minimum recursion. However i have no idea where to start.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Fold is for accumulating a value as you iterate over a list. That's now how heapsort works. In heapsort you take all the elements, make a heap out of them, and then extract elements one by one out of the heap.

Comment: Well once you create the heap, you can sort the data from that heap, which is what heapsort is. Here is the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort. So my question is how would you take the heap and apply the sorting algorithm to that heap to sort it?

Comment: Right. But what list are you iterating over here? You are taking a heap and repeatedly taking an element out of it to form a list, so it's an unfold.

Answer (score 2):

The Heapsort that the Wikipedia article describes works in two phases. First it rearranges the array into a Max-heap, with the largest item at position 0, and the rest of the items arranged to form a valid heap.

The next step sorts the heap by successively swapping the largest item with the item at the end of the array, reducing the count, and sifting the new item back down into the heap. Take the time to watch the animated GIF example on the Wikipedia page.

The sorting phase goes something like this:

```
last_item = array.Length - 1
while (last_item > 0)
{
    // move largest item to the end of the array
    // and replace with the item that was at the end
    swap(0, last_item)

    // decrease the count,
    // and sift the item down to its proper place
    --last_item
    sift_down(0, last_item)
}
```

When that's done, the array is in ascending order.

I don't see how `foldl` or `foldr` can help you here.

Comment: Okay so you pretty much can't use foldl or foldr to write a "sift-down" algorithm in SML. Thank you very much.